# enviar datos de el controlador a la vista, en plantilla sin framework

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un proyecto para la universidad y lo solicitaron sin framwork, y tengo un problema al momento de enviar los datos que obtengo en el controlador a la vista, este es el codigo de la consulta a la base de datos

```
public function SearchAllActividad(){
    $stmtdos = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades");
    var_dump($stmtdos)
    $stmtdos->execute();
    $a  = $stmtdos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $a;
}
```

esta es la funcion que tengo en el controlador para cargar la vista, y aqui es donde tengo el problema, no se como adjuntar la variable para que la informacion llegue a la vista.

```
public function ListView(){
    $a = $this->SearchAllActividad();
    var_dump($a);
    require './vistas/contenidos/administracionAct-view.php';
}
```

Comment: ya comprobaste que $a contiene los datos que necesitas??? puedes agregar el output del var_dump?

Comment: cual es el contenido de `administracionAct-view.php`

Comment: Tu vista objetivo, tiene que tener un metodo que reciba un parametro para que puedas pasar el resultado de tu query, sea como un array por ejemplo. Para recibirlo en tu view debes tener entonces una clase que debes instanciar, invocar el metodo y pasar tu argumento. Imagino que en view hay un echo o un print que devuelve el resultado a pantalla entonces

Answer (score 0):

Tu vista objetivo, tiene que tener un metodo que reciba un parametro para que puedas pasar el resultado de tu query, sea como un array por ejemplo. Para recibirlo en tu view debes tener entonces una clase que debes instanciar, invocar el metodo y pasar tu argumento. Imagino que en view hay un echo o un print que devuelve el resultado a pantalla entonces.

Esto requiere entender un poco como funciona la POO en PHP.

Por ejemplo tendrias una clase controlador

```php
Class Controller {
  public function __construct() {
      # Constructor
  }
  
  public function SearchAllActividad(){
    # Sustituyendo tu query solo como ejemplo
    $arr = [
        0 => [
              "user_id" => 1,
              "user_name" => "foo",
            ],
        1 => [
              "user_id" => 2,
              "user_name" => "bar",
            ],
        2 => [
              "user_id" => 3,
              "user_name" => "baz",
            ],
        ];
    
    # Devolver el array    
    return $arr;
  }
  
  public function ListView() {
      $arr = $this->SearchAllActividad();
      
      # Require lo que hace es cargar el archivo en tu ambiente de ejecucion
      require './ruta/de/tu/archivo/view.php';
      
      # Instanciar la clase de tu archivo view
      $output = new View();
      
      # Llamar al metodo y pasar el argumento
      $output->ImprimeActividad($arr);
  }
  
}
```

Luego en tu archivo view.php podrias tener algo como:

```php
class View {
    public function __construct(){
        # Constructor
    }
    
    public function ImprimeActividad($arr) {
        return print_r($arr);
    }
}
```

Luego en alguna parte estarias instanciando tu Controlador y ejecutando el metodo

```php
require './ruta/de/tu/archivo/controller.php';
$run = new Controller();
$run->ListView();
```

Lo anterior te imprimiria algo como:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [user_name] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_name] => bar
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [user_name] => baz
        )

)
```